# Move applications on SD card

Tags: android, sd-card

I'm testing Mobile App for Android platform, I have successfully installed the apk file and able to open but I’m not able to set the option to transfer the application to the SD card.

Would anybody suggest me what could be the reason for this, or do we need add some thing under AndroidManifest.xml tab?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this `android:installLocation=["auto" | "internalOnly" | "preferExternal"]` in your  `manifest` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` like this :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="string"
          android:sharedUserId="string"
          android:sharedUserLabel="string resource" 
          android:versionCode="integer"
          android:versionName="string"
          android:installLocation=["auto" | "internalOnly" | "preferExternal"] >
    . . .
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

> To allow the system to install your application on the external storage, modify your manifest file to include the android:installLocation attribute in the  element, with a value of either "preferExternal" or "auto".

from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html